# Tricky handling of associative array'ish data

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed, associative

I have a configuration file which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# lots of other stuff

declare -A PARTITIONS

PARTITIONS[ROOT,DEV]=/dev/mmcblk0p2
PARTITIONS[ROOT,MNT]=/
PARTITIONS[ROOT,FSTYPE]=ext4
PARTITIONS[ROOT,OPTS]='rw,suid,exec,auto,nouser,async,errors=remount-ro,noatime,nodiratime,commit=120 0 1'
PARTITIONS[ROOT,START]=64MB
PARTITIONS[ROOT,END]=6143.9MB
PARTITIONS[ROOT,OWNER]=root.root
PARTITIONS[ROOT,PERMS]=755

PARTITIONS[DATA,DEV]=/dev/mmcblk0p7
PARTITIONS[DATA,MNT]=/data
PARTITIONS[DATA,FSTYPE]=xfs
PARTITIONS[DATA,OPTS]='rw,noexec,auto,user,suid,noatime,nodiratime,async,logbufs=4,noquota 0 3'
PARTITIONS[DATA,START]=12288MB
PARTITIONS[DATA,END]=-1s
PARTITIONS[DATA,OWNER]=root.root
PARTITIONS[DATA,PERMS]=755
```

etc etc etc.

When I include it in the configuring script and iterate the keys of the AA, I get them in no particular order. The right parts of the keys (DEV, MNT...) are fixed, but not all are mandatory, while the left parts can be kind of random (just a mnemonic).

What I need is a list of the left parts to know which partitions must be created, then find out which of the right parts are defined (and if not, set a default value), so each partition will be well-defined before actually creating the partition, adding it to fstab, mounting...

We are talking about fresh systems here. The only two options to accomplish the task are Bash and/or Perl. No JavaScript, no Python, no C# Script, sorry. Sed and Awk are available. Because the setup steps before are done in Bash, I'd prefer a plain Bash (plus Sed/Awk, if needed) solution.

Of course its possible to change the configuration file. The only mandatory thing is to keep the flexibility of the left part of the keys.

Comment: I still don't really understand what you are trying to do ?

Comment: What does `iterate the keys of the AA` mean? Post the expected output given that input. The correct solution will be in awk, btw - the only bash part will be when it calls awk. A shell is an environment from which to call tools, not a tool to manipulate text, and the standard, general-purpose text manipulation tool that comes on all UNIX systems is awk.

Comment: If you need rich data structures, don't use `bash`.

Comment: Are the defaults fixed or do you need to know some of the other configs for that key to compute the defaults?

Comment: @123: This file (or a similar one) is part of a set of scripts to automate the setup of a certain flavor of Linux ("MiniBian") on Raspberry Pis. The default partition of this distribution is extremely small.

Because not all Pis do the same, it's mandatory to have the flexibility of a configuration file to control the scripts' behavior.

@EdMorton: In a more elaborate coding language, you'd write something like this:

`var aa = new Dictionary<string, string>();`
`foreach (var key in aa.Keys) {`
`// Do some fancy stuff with the keys`
`}`

@rici: The are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I tend to agree with @EdMorton's comment that awk is a superior tool, this problem is not particularly complicated, and bash is probably just fine:

```
# Find all the left-hand keys
declare -A keys
for key in "${!PARTITIONS[@]}"; do
  keys[${key%%,*}]=1
done

# Set defaults and/or check validity
errors=0
for key in "${!keys[@]}"; do
  # Set a default
  : "${PARTITIONS[$key,FSTYPE]:=ext4}"

  # Make sure a setting exists.
  # -v requires v4.2; otherwise use -n/-z. Maybe you
  # want those anyway, since a blank config might be an error.
  if [[ ! -v PARTITIONS[$key,MNT] ]]; then
    printf "MNT key missing for partition %s\n" "$key" >>/dev/stderr
    # Remove it from the set so it doesn't show up later
    unset keys[$key]
    ((errors++))
  fi

  # Etc.
done

# For debugging purposes, just print out the settings
for key in "${!keys[@]}"; do
  printf "$key:"
  for field in DEV MNT FSTYPE OPTS START END OWNER PERMS; do
    printf " %s=%b" $field "${PARTITIONS[$key,$field]}"
  done
  echo
done 

if ((errors)); then
  printf "Config errors. Not proceeding\n" >> /dev/stderr
  return 1
fi

# Do what needs to be done
# probably another loop over keys
```

Comment: While I agree with you regarding Ed's answer and his suggestion that Awk would be the tool of choice in such a case like mine, I'd better stick to a script language that I can read, like Bash script... At least after reading karakfa's suggestion and Ed's comment on it and while doing so feeling like a monkey staring at a clockwork ^^ (Note to myself: Read a good Awk primer!) Thanks, rici!

Comment: PS: Works perfectly nice, rici! You saved my day! ^^

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'[\\]\\[,]' '/^PARTITIONS/{a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2] OFS $3:$3}
                               END{for(k in a) print k ": " a[k]}' conf

DATA: DEV MNT FSTYPE OPTS START END OWNER PERMS
ROOT: DEV MNT FSTYPE OPTS START END OWNER PERMS
```

you can change the separator between the right components by setting up OFS.

Comment: Since I've told you many times before about these issues and it doesn't change the way you code I won't bring them up again after this time: You need to test for `$2 in a`, not `a[$2]` or the condition will fail when `a[$2]` evaluates to zero or null, and you need to parenthesize your ternary expressions or they will cause syntax errors in some contexts in some awks (and parenthesizing them makes the code more readable anyway) and you shouldn't redundantly specify the same value multiple times. So you should use `a[$2]=($2 in a?a[$2] OFS:"") $3` instead of `a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2] OFS $3:$3`.

Comment: I should definitely add Awk to my To-Learn-List. This seems even more dangerous than a solution in Perl ^^